# Sidebar scroll x amount, then fix beneath (also fixed) header?

Tags: jquery, css-position, sidebar

I'm trying to implement a fixed nav at the top, after header which is scrolled past (that much works fine at the moment) and a sidebar that scrolls down with the page, until between the first and second div elements in the sidebar, then fixes.

[EDIT: Here's the fiddle - [jsfiddle.net/rqHCx/5](http://jsfiddle.net/rqHCx/5)]

I tried to modify my working code for the nav bar, not worrying about scrolling past the first element for now:

```
$(function() {
    var side_offset_top = $('#side').offset().top;
    var side = function(){
        var scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scroll_top > side_offset_top) { 
            $('#side').css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top': 40, 'right': 0 });
        } else {
            $('#side').css({ 'position': 'relative' });
        }   
    };
    side();
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        side();
    });
});
```

But with this, the sidebar of course jumps right to the right side of browser - but I do not want to specify a pixel value for `'right': px` as then it will screw up with different screen widths.

How can I make it just not move horizontally, and be fixed in place vertically after scrolling to it?

Also, when I scroll back up, there's a 40px margin-top introduced, I assume I need to check for a return somehow, and remove that then?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it.

```
$(function() {
    var ad_offset_right = $('#side-wrap').offset().right;
    var ad = function(){
        var scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scroll_top > 490) { 
            $('.ad300x600').css({'position':'fixed', 'top':40, 'right':ad_offset_right});
        } else {
            $('.ad300x600').css({'position':'relative'});
        }   
    };
    ad();
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        ad();
    });
});
```

Where 490px is the distance to the `.ad300x600` class I want to fix, and 40px is the height of the nav bar fixed above the side bar.

Answer (score 1):

If you calculate its horizontal position when it is relative (in its correct horizontal position), you can use that number to when it is fixed. I added a top and right value for when it should go back to relative to reset its position.

```
$(function() {
    var side_offset = $('#side').offset();
    var side_offset_top = side_offset.top;
    var side_offset_right = side_offset.right;
    var side = function(){
        var scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scroll_top > side_offset_top) { 
            $('#side').css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top': 40, 'right': side_offset_right });
        } else {
            $('#side').css({ 'position': 'relative', 'top': 0, 'right': 0});
        }   
    };
    side();
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        side();
    });
});
```

Comment: Oh, thanks! I should have thought of that. D'oh. +1 for now, I'll check that when I get home. I still need to add a check back up, so it scrolls with the header correct?

Comment: Okay.. that's a step closer, thanks. But when the fixed horizontal nav hits the top, #side starts to scroll over it, then 40?px after that it jumps to the right again, fixed, and not scrolled down to the point between elements. I'll try and make a fiddle, but I've never used it before.

Comment: Bit of investigating - `side_offset_right` doesn't work. I think this is because the initial x position isn't set by CSS, it's `float:right` within a div wrapper of `margin:auto; width:960px;`. I don't know why it scrolls over the top of the horizontal nav though.

Comment: A fiddle with the relevant code would probably make it easier for me to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the help. See here: jsfiddle.net/rqHCx/5